# How to create a layout with rounded corners on only the top or bottom half?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I'm trying to add row items into a RecyclerView that looks like this:

[image]

The view layout has 2 versions; one with an image on the top half and one that only contains text. A few things make this a tricky layout to create;

1. The image is only rounded on the top
2. The textview bottom half is only rounded on the bottom
3. If the ImageView is gone, then the textview DOES have rounded top corners.

I'd prefer to have only one row layout and designed in XML. Is that possible, or do I need to create this layout in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using material cardview. Here's the xml code of the full layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="30dp"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#406cca"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#fb7500" />

    </LinearLayout>

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Remember, if the image is not there, just make the visibility of that particular imageview in your recyclerview to View.GONE in your code.

I hope you understood. If any queries, put a comment!

Here a pic of what this code looks like:
[image: Sample render of xml code]

Comment: This works. However if you attempt to use a ConstraintLayout instead of a LinearLayout everything goes to hell. It's unfortunate that Google makes creating layouts so difficult sometimes. With a ConstraintLayout the image refuses to go near the rounded corners :(

Comment: @szaske yes I understand your point. And in fact, I tried constraint layout instead of linear layout at first... I mean, you could actually achieve this same effect with constraint layout using vertical chains. But again, you also want that your imageView to vanish if there's no image source. So achieving that with vertical chain on, was a bit frustrating. So I think its best to use a vertical linear layout (correct me if I'm wrong somewhere)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a drawable, set the corners value in the drawable, and set the drawable as the background of the view you want to have the top rounded corners.
here is a working drawable:

```
<!--  res/drawable/rounded_edittext.xml -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    >
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:topRightRadius="15dp"/>
    <solid android:color="#ABC123"/>
   
</shape>
```

Comment: it will be working when you add `<solid android:color="#ABC123"/>` - some fulfiling color for showing rounded corners

Answer (score 1):

for image holder use this [library](https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView)

```
<com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
     android:id="@+id/imgUser"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="100dp"
     app:riv_corner_radius_top_left="5dp"
     app:riv_corner_radius_top_right="5dp"/>
```